# How to implement a React equivalent of Vue's IS attribute?

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to implement:

```
<div is='a' href='https://stackoverflow.com'>go to Stack Overflow</div>
```

To render into:

```
<a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>go to Stack Overflow</a>
```

What would be the most sensible approach to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do that, but here's one of them:

```js
const CustomComponent = (props) => {
  const {is, children, ...rest} = props
  return React.createElement(is, {...rest}, children)
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <CustomComponent
      is={'a'}
      href={'https://stackoverflow.com'}
    >
      go to Stack Overflow
    </CustomComponent>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

More on `React.createElement()` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement).